# Change $_Get value without reloading the whole page content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i have a folder called cars, and i have about 600 different images inside it, all of them have the same extension (.jpg), and all of their names are numbers from 1 to 600.

i show them up as a car gallery with Next and Previous buttons and their name value will be according to $_GET Variable called ( imgnumber ). everything is okay and working good until now,

**BUT**, When i click on the next or previous button the whole page reloading to show up the new image, i want to change the get variable value with JQuery and show the next or previous image without reloading the whole page content. i also want to give the image some beautiful effect during its load like as ( fade in )

This is my simple code to clarify my question more

```
<a href="cars.php?imgnumber=<?php echo $_GET['imgnumber']+1; ?>">NEXT IMAGE</a> 
<br />
<br />
<a href="cars.php?imgnumber=<?php echo $_GET['imgnumber']-1; ?>">PREVIOUS IMAGE</a> 

            <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <img src="/images/cars/<?php echo $_GET['imgnumber']; ?>.jpg" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: Try using "event.preventDefault" on the click event handler for the links.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="next">NEXT IMAGE</a>
```

```
<a id="prev">PREVIOUS IMAGE</a> 

            <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <img id="img" src="/images/cars/<?php echo $_GET['imgnumber']; ?>.jpg" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
```

The jQuery would be:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#next").click(function(e){
             e.preventDefault()


    $.ajax({url: "cars.php?imgnumber=<?php echo      $_GET['imgnumber']+1", success: function(result){
    $("#img").attr("src", "/images/cars/<?php echo $_GET['imgnumber']; ?>.jpg");
  }});
           });



        $("#prev").click(function(e){
                 e.preventDefault()
    $.ajax({url: "cars.php?imgnumber=<?php echo      $_GET['imgnumber']-1", success: function(result){
        $("#img").attr("src", "/images/cars/<?php echo $_GET['imgnumber']; ?>.jpg");
      }});
           });

         });
```

Comment: thank you for helping, but when i click on next or previous it doesn't do anything and the image doesn't change

Comment: @RayanAdams you will have to use jQuery ajax inside the click event handlers for the links. Then update the "src" attribute when the click event is triggered.

Comment: @RayanAdams checkout the edit on the code above and try it out.

Comment: i appreciate your help, the images changes now when i click on next or previous, but it doesn't show any images, i clicked right click on it to see the image path, but i see all of my ( cars.php ) codes as an url instead of my image path : ( https://localhost/%3Cscript%20src=%22https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E%3Ca%20id=%22next%22%3ENEXT%20IMAGE%3C/a%3E%3Ca%20id=%22prev%22%3EPREVIOUS%20IMAGE%3C/a%3E%3Ctable%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%3Cimg%20id=%22img%22%20src=%22/images/cars/2.jpg%22%20/%3E%3C/td%3E%3C/tr%3E%3C/table%3E%3Cscript%3E%20%20%20$(documen )